# diagnostic for MATLAB ODE

Tags: matlab

I am solving a stiff PDE in MATLAB using `ode15`, and it often freezes depending on the initial conditions.  I never actually get an error, it just won't finish even after 10 hours when it should take around 30 seconds to run.  I am experimenting with different spatial and time node intervals, but it is hard, because I don't get feedback.

Is there some sort of equivalent to diagnostic for `fsolve`?  `stats` is not useful because it only displays an output after `fsolve` is finished.

Comment: Perhaps you could run it through the profiler to see where it's getting stuch?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html) on `odeset`, and specifically the `stats` option. I think you basically just want to set `stats` to `on` and you will get some feedback.

Also, depending on your ODE, you may need a different solver. About half way down the page on [this page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) there is a list of most of the solvers available in MATLAB. Depending on whether your function is stiff or non-stiff, and how accurate you need to get, one of those might work better for you. Sometimes I just code them all in and comment out all but one until I find the one that runs the best for me, but check out the documentation on each if you want to find the "right" one for your application.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I must have skipped right over the `fsolve` statement to the `ode15` one. What is your syntax? Can you show us the code that is freezing?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusing because you refer to both `ode15s` and `fsolve` locking up. These are two completely different functions. One does numerical integration and the other solves for roots. Also, `fsolve` has no option called `'Stats'` (see `doc fsolve`). If you want continuous output from `fsolve` use:

```
options = optimist('Display','iter');
[x,fval,exitflag] = fsolve(myfun,x0,options)
```

This will display the iteration count, number of function evaluations, the function value, and other stuff depending on what algorithm you use (the alorithm can be adjusted via the `'Algorithm'` option). Again see `doc fsolve` for full details.

As far as the `'Stats'` option with `ode15s` goes, it's not going to give you very much information. I doubt that it will you figure out why your system is halting (if it even is `ode15s` that you have a problem with). What you can try is using an output function via the `'OutputFcn'` option of `odeset`. You can try the simple `odeprint` first:

```
options = odeset('OutputFcn',@odeprint)
```

which will print your state after each integration step. Type `edit odeprint` to see the code and how you might write your own output function if you need to do more.